# Is there a way to bypass the OverflowError limitation of Python rsa package?

Tags: python, rsa, python-3.6

I currently have a basic Python RSA encryption program that works fine on small files but has a OverflowError raised when I use it on a large file. I am wondering if there is any way around this limitation of the library. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import rsa

def load_keys():
    #load the public and private keys from the files generated in generate_keys()
    with open('/path/to/public/key', 'rb') as f:
        pubKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(f.read())
    with open('/path/to/private/key', 'rb') as f:
        privKey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(f.read())
    return pubKey, privKey

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    try:
        #return the decrypted method
        return rsa.decrypt(ciphertext, key).decode('ascii')
    except:
        return False

def encrypt(msg, key):
    #encrypts a message with RSA
    return rsa.encrypt(msg.encode('ascii'), key)


pubKey, privKey = load_keys()
with open ("/path/to/big/file", "rb") as f:
    message=str(f.readlines())

ciphertext = encrypt(message, pubKey)

#decrypt the message
plaintext = decrypt(ciphertext, privKey)
```

As mentioned if `message` is a small file this works but if it is a large file I receive:

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-bd999ad6731b> in <module>
     49 
     50 #encrypt the message with our public key, represents peer sending us a message
---> 51 ciphertext = encrypt(message, pubKey)
     52 with open('/path/to/encrypted/file', 'wb') as f:
     53         f.write(ciphertext)

<ipython-input-12-bd999ad6731b> in encrypt(msg, key)
     22 def encrypt(msg, key):
     23     #encrypts a message with RSA
---> 24     return rsa.encrypt(msg.encode('ascii'), key)
     25 
     26 def decrypt(ciphertext, key):

python3.6/site-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py in encrypt(message, pub_key)
    192 
    193     keylength = common.byte_size(pub_key.n)
--> 194     padded = _pad_for_encryption(message, keylength)
    195 
    196     payload = transform.bytes2int(padded)

python3.6/site-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py in _pad_for_encryption(message, target_length)
    112         raise OverflowError(
    113             "%i bytes needed for message, but there is only"
--> 114             " space for %i" % (msglength, max_msglength)
    115         )
    116 

OverflowError: 1994 bytes needed for message, but there is only space for 117
```

Is there anyway to overcome the limitation of `max_msglength` or to specify its value at runtime? Thank you in advance!

Please note that while similar my question differs from:
[Overflow Exception when encrypting message with python-rsa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677614/overflow-exception-when-encrypting-message-with-python-rsa#)

Comment: https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#working-with-big-files

Comment: It’s not so much a limitation of python-rsa as a limitation/constraint of RSA - and there are many results if you search for _RSA can only encrypt messages that are smaller than the key_

Comment: The right way to encrypt larger data is [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).